ConnectN GUI error how do I change my Grid or Frame to fix the problem
this is the error im getting i have tried to rebuild it multiple times but i cant seem to pick out what the error is. if anyone can help me out that would be great
java.lang.Error: no ComponentUI class for: edu.wm.cs.cs301.connectn.view.ConnectNGridPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=
package edu.wm.cs.cs301.connectn.view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import edu.wm.cs.cs301.connectn.model.ConnectNModel;
/**
 * The ConnectNFrame class represents the main from of the game
 * contains user interface elements like grid panel, column panel, and menu bar
 */
public class ConnectNFrame {
    
    private final JFrame frame;
    
    private final ConnectNModel model;
    
    public final ConnectNGridPanel connectNGridPanel;
    
    private JLabel turnCountLabel;

    /**
     * Constructs a ConnectNFrame object with the given ConnectNModel
     * @param model The ConnectNModel instance representing the game model
     */
    public ConnectNFrame(ConnectNModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.connectNGridPanel = new ConnectNGridPanel(model.getGameBoard().getBoard());
        this.frame = createAndShowGUI();
        this.showInstructionsDialog();
    }
    /**
     * Creates and displays the main GUI for the ConnectN game
     * @return The JFrame object for the main frame
     */
    private JFrame createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ConnectN");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                shutdown();
            }
        });

        // Creates panel to hold columnPanel and hintButton

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame.add(createTitlePanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                JPanel turnCountPanel = createTurnCountPanel();
                frame.add(turnCountPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
                centerPanel.add(connectNGridPanel);
                frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                int minFrameWidth = connectNGridPanel.getPreferredSize().width + 20; // Add a buffer
                int minFrameHeight = connectNGridPanel.getPreferredSize().height + 100;
                frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(minFrameWidth, minFrameHeight));
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("Frame size: " + frame.getSize());

            }
        });
        return frame;
    }
    
    private void showInstructionsDialog() {
        new InstructionsDialog(this);
    }
    /**
     * Creates the menu bar for the ConnectN game
     * @return the JMenuBar object for the menu bar
     */
    private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        
        // Menu for mode
        JMenu modeMenu = new JMenu("Mode");
        menuBar.add(modeMenu);
        
        // Kids mode
        JMenuItem kidsModeItem = new JMenuItem("Small");
        modeMenu.add(kidsModeItem);
        
        // Normal mode
        JMenuItem normalModeItem = new JMenuItem("Medium");
        modeMenu.add(normalModeItem);
        
        // Hard mode
        JMenuItem hardModeItem = new JMenuItem("Large");
        modeMenu.add(hardModeItem);
        
        JMenuItem instructionsMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Instructions...");
        instructionsMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                showInstructionsDialog();
            }
        });
        menuBar.add(instructionsMenuItem);
        
        return menuBar;
    }
    
    /**
     * Creates the title panel for the ConnectN game
     * @return the JPanel object representing the title panel
     */
    private JPanel createTitlePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));
        
        InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "cancelAction");
        ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();
        actionMap.put("cancelAction", new CancelAction());
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("ConnectN");
        label.setFont(AppFonts.getTitleFont());
        panel.add(label);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createTurnCountPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        turnCountLabel = new JLabel("Turn: " + model.getTurnCount());
        turnCountLabel.setFont(turnCountLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 16)); // Set font size to 16
        panel.add(turnCountLabel);

        return panel;
    }
    
    public void updateTurnCountLabel() {
        turnCountLabel.setText("Turn: " + model.getTurnCount());
    }
    
    /**
     * Shuts down the game, saves stats
     */
    public void shutdown() {
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    /**
     * resets the default colors of column panel
     */
    
    /**
     * sets the color of a specific letter button on the column
     * @param letter The letter associated with the button
     * @param backgroundColor The background color to set for the button
     * @param foregroundColor The foreground color to set for the button
     */
    
    
    /**
     * Repaints the grid panel
     */
    public void repaintConnectNGridPanel() {
        connectNGridPanel.repaint();
        
    }
    
    /**
     * repaints the hint button
     */
    /**
     * Returns JFrame object for the main frame
     * @return The JFrame object
     */
    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }
    /**
     * Performed when cancel action is triggered
     */
    private class CancelAction extends AbstractAction {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            shutdown();
        }
        
    }

}

package edu.wm.cs.cs301.connectn.view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import edu.wm.cs.cs301.connectn.model.Location;

public class ConnectNGridPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Location[][] board; // Representation of the game board
    private int rows;
    private int columns;

    public ConnectNGridPanel(Location[][] board) {
        this.board = board;
        this.rows = board.length;
        this.columns = board[0].length;
        // Initialize the grid panel
        initializeGridPanel();
        // Set preferred size
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(columns * 60, rows * 60)); // Adjust the multiplier based on your preference
    }

    private void initializeGridPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, columns));
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                JPanel cellPanel = new JPanel() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        super.paintComponent(g);
                        // No need to draw anything initially
                    }
                };
                cellPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                add(cellPanel);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int cellWidth = getWidth() / columns;
        int cellHeight = getHeight() / rows;

        // Loop through each location in the board
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                // Determine the position and size of the circle
                int x = j * cellWidth;
                int y = i * cellHeight;
                int diameter = Math.min(cellWidth, cellHeight) - 10;

                // Get the token from the Location object
                char token = board[i][j].getToken();

                // Draw blue or green circle based on the token
                if (token == 'B') {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                } else if (token == 'G') {
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    // Handle other cases if necessary
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                }

                // Draw the circle
                g.fillOval(x + (cellWidth - diameter) / 2, y + (cellHeight - diameter) / 2, diameter, diameter);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawConnectNResponse(Graphics2D g2d, Location location, Rectangle r) {
        char token = location.getToken();

        // Adjust the circle's position and size
        int diameter = Math.min(r.width, r.height) - 10;
        int x = r.x + (r.width - diameter) / 2;
        int y = r.y + (r.height - diameter) / 2;

        // Draw red or blue circle based on the token
        if (token == 'R') {
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        } else if (token == 'B') {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            // Handle other cases if necessary
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        // Draw the circle
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    }

}


